# IHeaderAngularComp on changes params

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag grid / angular and I have successfully redefine a custom header 
from IHeaderAngularComp.
Inside of the cusotm class I use agInit(params), as said in the documentation to get the custom param I set outside the grid.
It works really well except that on data I use inside the params come from a http request, but at the time the request resolves, the headers are already created, and the call to agInit is long gone ...
So I was curious about the use of a agChange or similar ?

here is the custom class ( really classic ) :

```
export class CustomMonthHeaderComponent implements IHeaderAngularComp  {

   private params: any;

  constructor() { }

  agInit(params) 
  {
     this.params = params; // this is not yet fully prepared at this time
  }

  // proposal / similar option : 
  agChange(params) 
  {
     this.params = params; // this is ok now yeah !
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ag-grid really, just plain old JS.

You can pass in a promise as a param and when it resolves, update the fields as necessary

```
export class CustomMonthHeaderComponent implements IHeaderAngularComp  {

  private params: any;
  private someField = "";

  constructor() { }

  agInit(params) 
  {
     this.params = params; // this is not yet fully prepared at this time
     this.params.getStuffForHeadersPromise.then((data) => {
         // this is ok now yeah !
         this.someField = data.someFieldValue;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for this solution, I HAVE NOT TRIED IT, but i will accept it as the answer it makes sense to me.

Comment: I just thought that you would want params to be ready at that point though.